# Difference between CURLOPT_HTTPPOST and CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Tags: http, curl, http-post, libcurl

While reading setopt function in  cURL I came across `CURLOPT_HTTPPOST` and `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, so just wanted to know the difference between the options

```
multipart/formpost(CURLOPT_HTTPPOST)
```

and

```
postfields(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS)
```

Where we should use each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[CURLOPT_HTTPPOST](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTHTTPPOST) sends a multipart/formdata HTTP POST that you create with [curl_formadd()](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_formadd.html) and friends. Example: [multi-post.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multi-post.html)

[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPOSTFIELDS) sends a "normal" POST with a content-type of x-url-form-encoded but with no encoding done by libcurl itself. Example: [simplepost.c](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplepost.html)

And really, you use the one that matches what the server end wants. You can very rarely select yourself in the client-side.

Comment: thank you for the examples! I also found example for POST with handling response: https://curl.se/libcurl/c/postinmemory.html